# Driving Force GT: Force Feedback and Wheel Rotation

Tags: controllers, force-feedback

I'm diving into the world of game development on PC and have a language agnostic question in regards to controller output.

I have in my possession a *Logitech Driving Force GT*. This particular steering wheel controller has force feedback (aka vibration or rumble) and the ability to turn the wheel through the game.

What are my options for interfacing with this advanced functionality (not the basic axis rotations and button presses)? I've read the DirectInput and xInput documentation with no luck. Is it like a propriety Logitech only API, or as simple as passing information via HID?

Any pointers that will lead me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft advises to use their **Direct Input** API. The following article is from 1998, bit might still apply.

http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/force.aspx

MSDN might be a useful starting point, too

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: DirectInput is actually deprecated. I am not sure if XInput (the replacement) supports programmable force feedback - it might only have rumble.